# Load removes previous PHP scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So i have this code:

```
<?php define('load', 'loaded'); ?>
<body>
    <a href="" id="load">Load</a>
</body>
```

and here is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').load('joke.php');
        })
    })
</script>
```

my joke.php contains:

```
<?php echo load; ?>
```

I wonder if there is a way that the loaded file can read previous scripts sir. Please help

Comment: How does `joke.php` relate to the first file you have here?

Comment: so if click the load, then the joke.php will be loaded in the body. The joke.php contains echo $load, however, after the file is loaded, it doesnt recognize the $load variable, even if i put it above the body or before html

Comment: `<?php $load = "loaded"; ?>` is gone on load. PHP is executes before the page builds. You could put that value in a JS variable then alert or do some JS function to output it after the AJAX execution.

Comment: You have to pass it using either POST (which doesn't work with load) or via the url as GET

Comment: i see, i see. Thank you sir! I thought .load() works like include

Comment: Wouldn't loading the contents inside a child of `<body>` solve this problem?

Comment: No, I am loading the whole page sir. I using the SPA approach in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so if click the load, then the joke.php will be loaded in the body. The joke.php contains echo $load, however, after the file is loaded, it doesnt recognize the $load variable, even if i put it above the body or before html

You have to pass the value back to the server from the client.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').load('joke.php?load=<php echo $load; ?>');
    })
})
</script>
```

Basically your URL will look like this `joke.php?load=loaded`,

Then in your `joke.php` you can retrive it by using `$_GET['load']`, or in your case `echo $_GET['load']`.

Alternatively you can use POST, but you can't do that using load.  You'll have to use `$.ajax` or `$.post` for that.

You can't access it the way you were doing it because the client and the server are 2 separate and distinct entities.

I suggest reading up on the differences between the client and the server and what is a client or server side language.  I would offer an explanation but it's outside the scope of this answer and there are plenty of sources on the internet that can do a better job of explaining then I can in a format like this (Stack Overflow).

The best I can do is think about putting that URL right in the browser (which is perfectly acceptable to test it).  Now with it in the browser URL bar, where does that value (for load) come from. It has to come from somewhere, this is essentially what you are doing with `load()`. You are making a separate and distinct request to the server from the client.

The only other way would be to store that data in some kind of persistent data storage, such as a file, a DB, the Session, etc.

Comment: Thank you sir, the only problem I had was I used a constant to which it was then unidentified when i loaded the joke.php.